# Rename [omni-focus] to [omnifocus]

Tags: support, tags

[OmniFocus](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus) is one word, however the tag [omni-focus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omni-focus) is hyphenated.
Can the tag be renamed [omnifocus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omnifocus) to reflect the correct word?

Comment: @grgarside Yes, please change it. While you're at it, change omni-graffle to omnigraffle as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[omni-focus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omni-focus) → [omnifocus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omnifocus) (11 posts, 2 more in history)

[omni-graffle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omni-graffle) → [omnigraffle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omnigraffle) (11 posts)